# What is the alternative to deprecated SearchType.SCAN in ElasticSearch >2.1?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch documentation mentions that the [SCAN search type is deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_21_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_scan_literal_deprecated), and users are advised to just specify a sort order by "_doc".

We switched to ES 2.2, and the old code still works:

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = esClient.prepareSearch(indexName)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
            .setTypes("File")
            .setScroll(new TimeValue(ES_SCROLL_TIMEOUT_MILLIS))
            .setQuery(query)  .setSize(ES_BATCH_SIZE).execute().actionGet();
```

where 'query' is a boolean query.
however trying this for the same query:

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = esClient.prepareSearch(indexName)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
                .addSort("_doc", SortOrder.ASC)
                .setTypes("File")
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(ES_SCROLL_TIMEOUT_MILLIS))
                .setQuery(query)  .setSize(ES_BATCH_SIZE).execute().actionGet();
```

doesn't get any results.
As a workaround, the deprecated code still works, but I am curious to know how it should be done with the updated API.

Comment: Did you update your client version as well?

Comment: yep my POM says 2.2.0